# Phishing Website Detection using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, detection, phishing

I have a semester project where I have to detect phishing website using ML. I have been using support vector binary classifier  which is trained on an existing dataset to predict that whether a website is legitimate or not. The problem is SVMs need high calculations to train our data and are delicate with noisy data. Therefore, there is a high chance of overfitting. Is there any other classification model which will help to optimize my model?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar project in my Engineering days, i used NB Classifier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).